# Pausable buffer with RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to implement a togglable auto-save feature using RxJS streams. The goal is to:

- While auto-save is enabled, send changes to the server as they come.
- While auto-save is disabled, buffer the changes and send them to the server when auto-save is re-enabled.

Here is what I came across with:

```js
autoSave$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
change$ = new Subject();

change$.pipe(
  bufferToggle(
    autoSave$.pipe(filter(autoSave => autoSave === false)),
    () => autoSave$.pipe(filter(autoSave => autoSave === true)),
  ),
  concatMap(changes => changes),
  concatMap(change => apiService.patch(change)),
).subscribe(
  () => console.log('Change sent'),
  (error) => console.error(error),
);
```

Thanks to `bufferToggle`, I'm able to buffer the changes while `autoSave` is off and send them when it's re-enabled.

Problem is that while `autoSave` is enabled, nothing passes through. I understand it's because `bufferToggle` ignores the flow coming while its opening observable doesn't emit.

I feel that I should have a condition there to bypass the `bufferToggle` while `autoSave` is enabled, but all my attempts miserably failed.

Any idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can buffer events in-between autosave *on* and *off* using `bufferToggle(on, off)`, and open a filtering window between *off* and *on* using `windowToggle(off, on)`. And then we merge those together:

[image: pausable buffer with bufferToggle and windowToggle]

```js
const on$ = autoSave$.filter(v=>v);
const off$ = autoSave$.filter(v=>!v);

const output$ =
  Observable.merge(
    changes$
      .bufferToggle(
        off$,
        ()=>on$
      )

    changes$
      .windowToggle(
        on$,
        ()=>off$
      )
  )
  .flatMap(x=>x) // < flattern buffer and window
```

Play with this example at **https://thinkrx.io/gist/3d5161fc29b8b48194f54032fb6d2363**

* *Please, note that since buffer wraps values in Array — I've used another [`flatMap(v=>v)`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/mergeMap/) in the example to unwrap buffered values. You might want to disable this particular line to get arrays from buffers mixed with raw values.*

Also, check my article "[Pausable Observables in RxJS](https://medium.com/@kddsky/pauseable-observables-in-rxjs-58ce2b8c7dfd)" to see more examples.

Hope this helps

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Using `windowToggle` is very elegant :) BTW, the playground you use is great, I think it'll be useful.

Comment: @frankie567 , glad that it helped. I've been working on that playground for a while, so its great to get a nice feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.
Just one observable to play / pause

```typescript
export type PauseableOptions = 'paused' | 'playing'
export function pauseableBuffered(pauser$: Observable<PauseableOptions>) {
  return function _pauseableBuffer<T>(source$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    let initialValue = 'paused'
    // if a value is already present (say a behaviour subject use that value as the initial value)
    const sub = pauser$.subscribe(v => initialValue = v)
    sub.unsubscribe()

    const _pauser$ = pauser$.pipe(startWith(initialValue), distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1))

    const paused$ = _pauser$.pipe(filter((v) => v === 'paused'))
    const playing$ = _pauser$.pipe(filter((v) => v === 'playing'))

    const buffer$ = source$.pipe(bufferToggle(paused$, () => playing$))

    const playingStream$ = source$
      .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(_pauser$),
        filter(([_, state]) => state === 'playing'),
        map(([v]) => v)
      )

    return merge(
      buffer$.pipe(
        mergeMap(v => v)
      ),
      playingStream$
    )
  }
}
```

```typescript
const stream$ = new Subject<number>()
const playPause$ = new BehaviorSubject<PauseableOptions>('playing')

const result: number[] = []

const sub = stream$.pipe(pauseableBuffered(playPause$))
 .subscribe((v) => result.push(v))
```