# How to pause a buffer from one source in RXJS?

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream of events coming through via `fromEventPattern` like so:

`fromEventPattern<IPsEvent>(addEventHandler).subscribe(ps$);`

Due to business quirks, I expect that I will sometimes get an exception thrown, at which point I want to queue up the events and refire once that error state is resolved.

I've been trying the solution from [Pausable buffer with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829140/pausable-buffer-with-rxjs) to no avail. I am thinking it's because they are able to toggle through a separate observable whereas this is kind of asking to pause itself midstream. In the linked example I have `blockingCallsAllowed$` rather than `autoSave$`. Here is my latest try:

```js
const source$ = new Subject<IPsEvent>();

const blockingCallsAllowed$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
const on$ = blockingCallsAllowed$.pipe(filter((v) => v));
const off$ = blockingCallsAllowed$.pipe(filter((v) => !v));

source$
  .pipe(
    map(() => {
      try {
        // line will throw exception at certain times
        myFunction();
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        const i = setInterval(() => {
          try {
            myFunction();
            console.log('good again');
            blockingCallsAllowed$.next(true);
            clearInterval(i);
          } catch (er) {
            // still in flux
          }
        }, 50);
        return false;
      }
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(blockingCallsAllowed$);

const output$ = merge(
  source$.pipe(bufferToggle(off$, () => on$)),
  source$.pipe(windowToggle(on$, () => off$)),
).pipe(concatMap(from));

output$.subscribe((evt) => {
  console.log('After buffers', evt);
});

// Add events from the Ps API to the event stream
fromEventPattern(addEventHandler).subscribe(source$);
```

Everything fires fine until the first exception and then it never outputs what it had buffered away, even though it fires that things are good again in `console.log`.

I am thinking there is some timing issue around relying on `source$.pipe` in the same execution and then the interval running later with `.next`. Can't nail it though after many different permutations of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to implement. Though if you want to keep retrying `myFunction()` every 50ms until it succeeds and stop processing other events while this happens, `concatMap` basically does all that for you.

It will buffer emissions from the source while it waits for the inner observable to complete.

So what you're after might look like this:

```ts
source$.pipe(
  concatMap(_ => of(true).pipe(
    tap(_ => myFunction()),
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      delay(50)
    ))
  ))
).subscribe();
```

Comment: as far as I understand the case, I think this is a great solution!

Comment: Ah yeah this is way better than my delayWhen solution I ended up doing that is quite similar but more convoluted.